# Is that possible to transfer already installed Ubuntu to a bootable USB stick?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb, disk-image

I would love to transfer my modified and configured Ubuntu installation to a bootable pendrive so I could use it later anywhere.

I hope that it's achievable and there's already been made some magical software that'd help me create the image of my system.. like iso.. or something similar that later I could make bootable.

I know that there must've been many questions about preparing bootable stick with ubuntu... but doing just that wouldn't fully satisfy me.

I believe in You Guys ;)

Comment: Bootable disk cloning software might be a solution.

Comment: Would you kindly give me an example of such software?

Comment: [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php) is a nice solution, but I can't guarantee it'll let you clone to another USB drive. Also remember that the target probably needs to be at least 32GB.

Comment: I didn't know clonezilla could do this.
I mean..  Can I get an .iso from that?

Comment: No, Clonezilla can't do that, but it isn't really a plausible thing, since you can just zip your OS using a LiveUSB/CD and rename it to an ISO if you want a full archive. Read @WhosUrDaddy's answer. It seems like it might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, Systemback provides this functionality.

To install enter the following commands in a terminal window.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

Start Systemback
Select 'Live System Create'
When finished 'Convert to .iso'
Burn ISO to USB using the integrated Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: Does this keep modifications or just create a normal LiveISO?

Comment: No this keeps all modifications made to the system itself including updates installed programs/applications and also has the option to include your documents, pictures and files from each user account.  It is EXACTLY what you are looking for!

Comment: Then I am definitely upvoting. This is quite interesting.

Comment: Many thanks @WhosUrDaddy 
Definetely gonna try it.

Comment: Many 'your welcomes' @ Bart...

Answer (score -1):

There is [this tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-your-own-live-linux-cd-or-usb-distribution/) for Debian and since Ubuntu is Debian-based (and they talk about this fact on the linked page), give it a shot.

Comment: The question is not asking about LiveUSB creation. It is asking about either cloning the OS to USB or making an ISO out of the OS. Also, since links can go dead, it's better to link your source and paraphrase its instructions.

Comment: @Zacharee1 It's unclear whether he wants a changeable or fixed system. Assuming he wants a changeable system is just as wrong as assuming he wants a fixed one. And there is archive.org to help you with links that don't work any more.

Comment: He specifically said he wanted the exact OS he had, with documents, updates and the like. Simply creating a LveUSB does not do this. It is at least good practice to paraphrase the source, if not a rule.

Comment: It is a rule that you need to transfer instructions from your source.